# Change the PORT of Apache installed with WAMP

Tags: apache-2.2

I need to change the Apache's Port running under WAMP, because it is Clashing with the IIS, I tried to edit the httpd.conf and change the port 80 to some other port, but the WAMP seems to use the same port not matter what. :(

I am not being able to use the WAMP, without the Apache module running, both MYSQL and PHP are running but I cannot the register APACHE Service, unless it uses a free port.

Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *should* be trivial: on the `httpd.conf` change the `Listen 80` directive to other port, but [looking at the forums](http://www.wampserver.com/phorum/read.php?2,13744) seems to be a little more complicated than that. I suggest you to check the thread and see if you can get anything out of it.

Comment: Didn't you read my question, I have changed the port from httpd.conf, but no matter what, Wamp server uses the same port.

Comment: I read, and suggested that if you already changed the port you should read that thread and make sense of what they say there.